# unable to retrieve data from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have created some users and stored them in a mongoDB users database in a users collection. I am using Studio 3T to make sure the users are stored. In my dal.js file, I have the code that is supposed to retrieve the users data. In my server.js file I am defining routes to see the data. But the promises in the dal.js are not being resolved and thus the paths in server.js cannot GET the routes. Can anybody see what am I doing wrong here?

here is dal.js:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
// or as an es module:
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

async function main() {
    let db;
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to db server');
   db = client.db('users');

  return db;
}
main()

// create user accout
 function create(name, email, password, db) {
    db = client.db('users');
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
        const collection = db.collection('users');
        const doc = {name, email, password, balance: 0};
        collection.insertOne(doc, {w:1}, function(err, result){
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        })
    })
}

// all users 
function all(db) {
    db = client.db('users');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const customers = db
      .collection('users')
      .find({})
      .toArray(function (err, docs) {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
        console.log('Collection:',docs)
      });
    });
  }

module.exports = {create, all};
```

here is server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var dal = require('./dal.js');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  };
  
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));

  app.get("/", (req, resp) => {
    resp.send("App is Working");
});

app.get("/index", (req, resp) => {
    resp.send("hello world");
});

app.get("/accounts", (req, res) => {
        const docs =  dal.all();
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs);
});

// create user account
app.get('/account/create/:name/:email/:password/:balance', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const user = await dal.create(
            req.params.name,
            req.params.email,
            req.params.password,
            req.params.balance
        );
        console.log(user);
        res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});


app.get('/account/all', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const docs = await dal.all();
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Running on port 3001.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dal.js file
In your 'main()' function you are connecting to the server but you're not exporting
the connected database. You should export the db object.

```
const{ MongoClient }= require('mongodb')

const url='mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client= new MongoClient(url)

async function connectToDatabase(){
await client.connect();
console.log('Connected successfully to db server');
return client.db('users');

//Export the connected database
module.exports={connectToDatabase}
```

In the 'create' and 'all' functions, you don't need to pass the 'db' parameter. Instead, you can use the exported 'connectToDatabase' function to obtain the database connection.

Modify your dal,js file like

```
const { connectToDatabase } = require('./dal.js');

// ...

async function create(name, email, password) {
    const db = await connectToDatabase();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const collection = db.collection('users');
        const doc = { name, email, password, balance: 0 };
        collection.insertOne(doc, { w: 1 }, function (err, result) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        });
    });
}

async function all() {
    const db = await connectToDatabase();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .find({})
            .toArray(function (err, docs) {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
                console.log('Collection:', docs);
            });
    });
}

module.exports = { create, all };
```

Now in your server.js file

In your '/accounts' route handler you need to use a 'await' when calling 'dal.all()' because it returns a promise

```
app.get("/accounts", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const docs = await dal.all();
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});
```

I hope it helps